# Qt 4.7.4 and minGW 4.7.2 libs

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator, mingw32

I have 2 different projects build with MinGW 4.7.2 using CMake and I need to link these to a Qt graphical app. Qt version is 4.7.4. OS is Windows 8 64bits.

The problem is that when I try to compile I get a huge amount of undefined references. After some research, I think it's because my version of Qt use minGW 4.4. Is that correct ?
Is there any way I could make the app work with my current configuration ?

If not, is there a different version of Qt that could work ? From what I saw the only option is to compile Qt with minGW 4.7.2. I tried and got errors when building it so if there's an easier way to make things work it would be great.

I also tried to compile my 2 projects with MinGW 4.4 but it crashs when i execute them so I have to keep MinGW 4.7.2 since I don't plan on doing more modifications to these 2 projects.

Also, as of now I use the mingw from mingw.org on a 64 bits laptop. I haven't got any problem because of that since now but maybe i should change to one of the mingw64 alternative ?

Comment: So, I decided to try and compile my projects with minGW 4.4 and I'm still getting the same undefined reference errors when compiling my qt app. Could the issue be something else ?